# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '103545' could not be parsed at index 2

Tags: java, date, datetime, datetime-format, java-time

I'm trying to parse two different dates and calculate the difference between them, but the next error appears:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '103545' could not be parsed at index 2

Here's the code:

```
    String thisDate= mySession.getVariableField(myVariable).toString().trim();
    
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
    LocalDate theDate= LocalDate.parse(thisDate, formatter);
```

Comment: So what date would you expect "103545" to be parsed to?

Comment: So month 35? And where is the century of the year? Your formatting pattern does not at all match your input.

Comment: I get `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '103545' could not be parsed at index 4` (not index 2). Which leads me to suspect that you haven’t correctly pasted the exact code that you were running?

Comment: Marina, I’m curious to read whether you got any further with your problem because it looked a bit funny, frankly. Whether there’s more we can say to help?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

That’s as expected (approximately).

Your format pattern string, `ddMMyyyy` specifies two digits day of month, two digits month and (at least) four digits year for a total of (at least) eight (8) digits. So when you give it a string consisting of only 6 digits, parsing will necessarily fail.

If your user or another system is required to give you a date in `ddMMyyyy` format and they give you `103545`, they are making an error. Your validation caught the error, which is a good thing. You will probably want to give them a chance to try again and give you a string like for example `10112021` (for 10 November 2021).

In case (just guessing) `103545` was meant to denote a time of day, 10:35:45 then you need to use the `LocalTime` class for it, and you also need to change the format pattern string to specify hours, minutes and seconds instead of year, month and date.

```
    String thisDate = "103545";

    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmss");
    LocalTime theTime = LocalTime.parse(thisDate, formatter);
    System.out.println(theTime);
```

Output from this snippet is:

> 10:35:45

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the date parser has to recieve a date in the format specified (in this case "ddMMyyyy")

For example, this is what you would need to input for the parser to return a valid date:

```
String thisDate = '25Sep2000';

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyy");
LocalDate theDate = LocalDate.parse(thisDate, formatter);
```

I think what you want is to convert a date in milliseconds to a date with a specific format. This is what you can do:

```
//Has to be made long because has to fit higher numbers
long thisDate = 103545;    //Has to be a valid date in milliseconds
  
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");    //You can find more formatting documentation online
Date theDate = new Date(thisDate);

String finalDate = formatter.format(theDate);
```

Comment: No, no one wants to use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are troublesome and long outdated. The millisecond thought may be right (though I am sceptical), but if it is, use `Instant` from java.time for it. You may convert to other java.time types as necessary.

Comment: After correcting the quotes in your first code snippet I got `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '25Sep2000' could not be parsed at index 2`.